# Calculate number of valid tickets at a given time (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make use of our data from ticket sales to calculate occupancy of different locations.

I have a table with the following information:

- Time_in (DATETIME)
- Time_out (DATETIME)
- Location (VARCHAR)

Is there a way to calculate how many tickets are valid at a given location at a given time?
For example, how many tickets are valid at, let's say '2014-05-02 16:00:00'?

Anthony Raymond : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbee/1

Comment: Can you create a test environement please ? with : http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I imagine this would be done with maths and two counts, one to count the new tickets that were activated, and one to count the number that have been deactivated, the difference would then be the number that are active.

Comment: @Anthony Raymond - as you requested : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbee/1

Comment: @scragar : I can do this in Excel, but for this task it is much more practical to do it in a SELECT from mySQL.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it right after i ate. ;)

Comment: @kjstan How do you consider a ticket as 'valid' ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbee/4 <-- That sort of thing was what I was suggesting.

Comment: I've come this far : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbee/6

Comment: @kjstan You need to use a less than, if you just check the hour the whole thing breaks down because there may be records deactivated that hour that were activated in another. Can you explain what exactly you're expecting to be able to get?

Comment: @scragar : Thank you for your help so far. Your suggestion is nice, but I may have been unclear when I posted my question. I need it to be universal as I want to apply it to a huge set of data on a daily basis.

I want the following colums :
- Location
- Date
- One column for each hour during the day
    I want the total number of valid tickets for each column.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Is this any closer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbbee/22

Comment: @scragar : Great suggestion. I'm just missing the possibility to loop through a set of dates. The ideal solution would be to start at the oldest date in the database and end at the last date (And adding the column 'date' to the result.)

Comment: @kjstan can you expand on "just missing the possibility to loop through a set of dates"? I don't understand how you're specifying the dates to loop through, are they coming from another table? Passed in as parameters to a SPROC? Just every date mentioned in the `Transaction` table? If you can answer that question I'll see what I can do.